Stochastic Processes with Dynamically Changing Parameters
This is a question I have had for many years and have always wondered about it.
In my home country, French Fries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_fries) are a very tasty snack. However, we don't always have access to deep fryers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_fryer) and end up cooking French Fries in the oven.

To do this, we take a tray and scatter the French Fries on a tray and place them into an oven. After a few minutes, we shake the tray in an attempt to flip the French Fries and put them back in the oven. Then, they are ready to eat!
However, I have always wondered: If we turn this situation into a math problem (e.g. assume each fry has two sides, each fry has a probability of being flipped when the pan is shaking) - after some time has passed, what percent of the fries will be undercooked, overcooked and cooked just right?
In the past, I posted this question about a simple version of this problem (e.g. Cooking French Fries as a Stochastic Process?), but I was wondering if it is possible to add more layers of reality to this problem. For example:

Assume that each fry has two sides
100 fries are randomly placed on a pan in the oven
A fry needs to be cooked two minutes on each side to be considered perfectly cooked. Anything more is overcooked and anything less is undercooked
The pan is shaken once every minute
At time=0, there is a 0.5 probability that the movement of the pan will result in a fry being flipped . If the fry is flipped, there is a 0.5 probability that it will land on any given side

In the end, we would have information such as: After 3 minutes, fry #1 was cooked 2 times on side A and 1 time on side B, fry #2 was cooked 3 times on side A and o times on side B, etc.
I am interested in adding these two conditions to the problem:

As times goes on, if a fry is not selected for flipping, it starts to get burnt and stick to the pan, thus making it even less likely to be flipped. E.g. If a fry is not selected, the probability of being flipped decreases from $0.5$, $0.5 - 2n$, $0.5 - 3n$, etc. However, if this
burning fry is flipped and lands on the other side, the probability counter resets
If a fry is selected for flipping, let's assume that it is more likely to land on the side that is more cooked by a factor of $m$ (e.g. 50-50, 51-49, 52-48, etc.)

My Question: As I understand, the states of these 100 fries cooking over some time period can be modelled as a stochastic process. However, it is a complicated stochastic process as the transition probabilities and parameters themselves are dynamically changing.
I tried to simulate a similar problem like this over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78284874/r-dynamically-updating-the-probabilities-of-a-pancake-being-flipped ... but I was wondering about some of the following questions.
For example, on average:

How many minutes are required for each fry to be cooked at least 2 minutes on each side?
In this time period, how many of the fries will have been overcooked on one side? Overcooked on both sides?
In this time period, how burnt will be the fry that was overcooked the most?

For such situations with complex stochastic processes having multiple parameters that can change over the course of the process : Is it possible to analyze these problems using exact formulas, or can they only be simulated?
Thanks!

First of all, I am going to make a slight modification to the information presented:
OP talks about probability of flip and probability of landing on the right side. Here, it seems as though flip means whether the fry got lifted in the air while shaking. To simplify it, I am going to call "flip" as the event where the fry got lifted in shaking and fell on the opposite side. This means that if it lifted, but fell on the same side without rotating in the air or if it lifted and rotated twice in the air and fell on the same side again, I will call it no flip.
Let's denote the two sides of the fry as $0$ and $1$. If we denote the state of the fry after each minute, we will get a string of 1s and 0s. Of course the probability of those are state dependent. But, whatever be the probability, if we cook 100 fries for $\le 3$ minutes, we will get a string of 3 bits, of which either 1s or 0s will not have 2 entries. This means that all the 100 fries willl be undercooked. Similarly if we cook for $\ge 5$ minutes, all the fries will be burnt (as each of the fry will have $3$ or more $0/1$). The only way we can (possibly) cook a fry correctly is by cooking it for 4 minutes. But whether it will get cooked perfetly or be undercooked or burnt depends on probability.
If we take a string of 4 bits, only the following combinations will be cooked right (as they have equal 0s and 1s):
$$0011$$
$$1100$$
$$0101$$
$$1010$$
$$0110$$
$$1001$$
Note that probability for $0011$ and $1100$ can be computed with the same formula and similarly $0101$ and $1010$ can be computed with the same formula. And $0110$ and $1001$ can be computed with the same formula.
Probability for $0011$ as well as $1100$ is
$$0.5 (1-(0.5-n)) (0.5-2n)(1-(0.5-n)) = -n^3 - 0.75n^2 + 0.0625$$
Probability for $0101$ as well as $1010$ is
$$0.5(0.5-n)(0.5-n)(0.5-n) = -0.5n^3 + 0.75n^2 - 0.375n + 0.0625$$
Probability for $0110$ as well as $1001$ is
$$0.5(0.5-n)((1-(0.5-n))(0.5-2n) = n^3 - 0.25n^2 - 0.25n + 0.0625$$
Here, n is a fraction that OP has chosen (but no matter what n is chosen after sufficiently long time, the expressions like 0.5-n or 0.5-2n etc will become negative, so we have to bound the total time to keep the probability non-negative, OR change the formula to something like $\frac{0.5}{1+k n}$ to keep it positive regardless of time.
The total probability of a fry being perfectly cooked after exactly 4 minutes is the sum of the above expressions, which (for $n=0$) is $\frac38$. For all the 100 fries to be perfectly cooked, the probability drops down to $(\frac38)^{100}$, assuming the fries are independent random variables.

The next time you cook fries, cook it for 4 minutes, manually flip the fries by looking at the done/undone ones and enjoy, as mathematically getting it right seems rather risky :)

I realized that I have not answered your exact questions. I would suggest looking at the problem of finding at least 2 $1$s in a binary string here: https://oeis.org/A000295

@ Sirni: thank you so much for your answer! I love your creativity!

Do you have any idea about this question over here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4903926/when-is-the-hitting-time-of-a-random-walk-infinite
