When is the hitting time of a Random Walk infinite?
Recently I posted this question here about different scenarios where two Random Walks can intersect: Bounded Random Walks vs Non-Bounded Random Walks
I realized that this question might be too complicated and decided to ask a simpler question involving the Hitting Times of a single Random Walk.
For this problem, let's define a simple Random Walk $X(t)$ such that $x_0$ is its position at time=0:
$$
X(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
x_0 & \text{if } t = 0 \\
X(t-1) + S_x(t) & \text{if } t > 0 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
S_x(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
+1 & \text{with probability } p= p_1 \\
-1 & \text{with probability } p= 1- p_1
\end{cases}
$$
Now, I am interested in considering the following scenarios:


Unconstrained Integer Domain:  $x(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$
Constrained Integer Domain: $a < X(t) < b$, such that $X(t), a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$
Unconstrained Continuous Domain: $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}$
Constrained Continuous Domain: $a < X(t) < b$, such that  $x(t) , a,b \in \mathbb{R}$
Exact Meeting: $x(t) = c_1$
Meeting within Range: $| x(t) - c_2| \leq c_1$

All together, this would result in 8 scenarios ($\tau$ is the stopping condition/hitting time in all these scenarios):

Scenario 1: Integer, Constrained, Exact Meeting
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{Z}, a < X(t) < b, X(t) = c_1\}$$
Scenario 2: Integer, Constrained, Within Range
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{Z}, a < X(t) < b, |X(t) - c_2| \leq c_1\}$$
Scenario 3: Integer, Unconstrained, Exact Meeting
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{Z}, X(t) = c_1\}$$
Scenario 4: Integer, Unconstrained, Within Range
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{Z}, |X(t) - c_2| \leq c_1\}$$
Scenario 5: Continuous, Constrained, Exact Meeting
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{R}, a < X(t) < b, X(t) = c_1\}$$
Scenario 6: Continuous, Constrained, Within Range
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{R}, a < X(t) < b, |X(t) - c_2| \leq c_1\}$$
Scenario 7: Continuous, Unconstrained, Exact Meeting
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{R}, X(t) = c_1\}$$
Scenario 8: Continuous, Unconstrained, Within Range
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0 : X(t) \in \mathbb{R}, |X(t) - c_2| \leq c_1\}$$

Can someone please help me understand how to derive probability distributions for the hitting times in each of the scenarios, take the expected value of the hitting times in each of these scenarios so I can understand which ones have infinite hitting times and which ones do not?
Thanks!
Note: In case anyone is interested, here is the computer code (R programming language) used for creating this flow chart:
root <- Node$new("Root")
integerNode <- root$AddChild("Integer")
continuousNode <- root$AddChild("Continuous")

=for (i in 1:2) {
    child <- integerNode$AddChild(ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, "Unconstrained", "Constrained"))
    child$AddChild("Exact Meeting")
    child$AddChild("Within Range")
}

for (i in 1:2) {
    child <- continuousNode$AddChild(ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, "Unconstrained", "Constrained"))
    child$AddChild("Exact Meeting")
    child$AddChild("Within Range")
}

graph <- ToDiagrammeRGraph(root)


DiagrammeR::render_graph(graph)


Hi @stats_noob, this is just a comment for now. For the $+/- 1$ case, each step for one of the two walks has probability of $\frac12$ for $+1$ and $-1$. After n steps, the sum disribution (pdf) for that walker is convolution of the initial PDF n times. Similarly you have the sum distribution from the second walker. Then the gap between them after n steps is subtraction of their sums. This is another convolution (but without flipping the second term that you usually do for convolution, because you are subtracting). The probability that they will meet is the probability at the value $0$.

The PDF after n convolutions follows (pascals triangle numbers)/2^n. https://oeis.org/A007318

There is a closed form expression for the PDF of meeting together after n steps based on this. I will need time to post a proper answer with an explicit formula, but someone may beat me to it (which will benefit your cause anyway) :)

@Srini: thank you so much for your replies! much appreciated!

Since any allowed step has the length $1$, it seems that the continuous scenarios are essentially the same as the respective integer scenarios.

It seems that in Unconstrained case instead of the random walks $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$
we can consider the random walk $Y(t)=X_1(t)-X_2(t)$ such that $Y(0)=0$ and
$$
Y(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } t = 0 \
Y(t-1) + S(t) & \text{if } t > 0
\end{cases},
$$
where
$$
S(t) =
\begin{cases}
+2 & \text{with probability } p_1(1-p_1) \
0 & \text{with probability } p_1^2+(1- p_1)^2 \
-2 & \text{with probability } p_1(1-p_1)
\end{cases}.
$$

I will expand my comment now as an answer. I assume that there are $2$ walkers who both start at the same point and they both walk with the same random pdf (whereas in the other question you linked, they both start at different point and also their random walks have different PDFs).
The basic principle is that for each walker, each step is independent and it has a PDF given by $P(+1) = p$ and $P(-1) = 1-p$. Now, given this step PDF, we can compute walk PDF (of the sum of the distance covered) by convolving the step PDF as many times as the number of steps taken (because they are iid and we are seeking the sum). See Wiki.
So let's see how the walk sum PDF looks after each step. I am going to show an explicit formula for $P(+1) = P(-1) =\frac12$. The principle for deriving for $P(+1) \ne P(-1)$ is the same, but may need more computation.
After Step $1$:

After Step $2$: Convolve step PDF $2$ times (strictly meaning $1$ convolution operator and $2$ arguments)

...
After Step $10$: Convolve step PDF $10$ times (strictly meaning $9$ convolution operators and $10$ arguments)

If you see the pattern, the numerators are from Pascal's triangle. The denominator is $2^{n}$, where $n$ is the number of steps.
The PDF after even number of steps has non-zero values only at even distance units and similarly after odd number of steps, the PDF has non-zero values only at odd distance units.
We can ignore the even/odd distance units (because the second walker would also be at the same even/odd position as the first walker) and simply see a pattern of $\frac{\binom{n}{0}}{2^{n}}$, $\frac{\binom{n}{1}}{2^{n}}$, $\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{2^{n}}$ ... $\frac{\binom{n}{n}}{2^{n}}$ in the walk sum PDF.
The walk sum PDF is identical for both walkers.
Now, let's look at the difference in their walk sums as another random variable. Because the PDF of the walk sum is symmetric in my simplification, we can simply convolve the PDF of the walk sums now. But in your example with $P(+1) \ne P(-1)$, you have to take care not to flip the PDF like you normally do with convolution. Also luckily we are only interested in the probability that they would meet after $n$ steps. This translates to the difference between their walk sums being $0$. Because we are deriving the outer PDF layer by convolving the walk sum PDF from each walker, we can simply do a term-wise multiplication (which corresponds to convolution and then looking at $0$ shift).
Putting it all together, the probability for $0$ difference in sum after $n$ steps is
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{2}}{2^{2n}}$$
The above formula is the PDF for meeting after n steps. The graph of that is shown below.

You have asked a lot of questions in your post and I am answering only one case, but I hope you can use similar principles for the rest of your cases too (although they are more mathematically involved).

thank you so much for your answer! Its very detailed and informative!

If you have time later in the week, can you please show me how to solve the other cases (not in as much detail if its inconvenient)? Thank you so much!

I didn't understand the mathematical notation you have given for your cases. In constrained cases, crudely speaking, is there a wall beyond which you cannot walk further and the only allowed move is to walk back one step?

Note that for meeting within a range in my special case is a simple modification to my formula. We calculated the last convolution with zero shift. If you want to find the distribution for within 2m step sizes(as the gap between the walkers is always an even multiple of step size, including 0, which corresponds to them meeting), you simply have to add up the convolutions for zero shift, 2 shifts, 4 shifts etc up to 2m. The square term in binomial came from zero shift. Now you will get a slightly bigger formula. But the probability will obviously increase by relaxing the meeting point gap.

Another question for you is for noon integer cases, are you saying that the step size is a bound real number? If so, that case, along with exact meeting is the only one that has zero probability, no matter how many steps you take. But even in that case, if you relax the meeting gap, there will be a non zero probability of meeting that gap after every step. Intuitively, it's an area under the pdf for some chosen gap. Obviously exact meeting means the integral for the area drops to 0 as a limit.

@ Srini: thank you for your reply and sorry for the delay in replying to you. my appologies


Question: " In constrained cases, crudely speaking, is there a wall beyond which you cannot walk further and the only allowed move is to walk back one step?" Answer: Exactly. In the constrained cases, the constraints are acting like a wall. For example. Suppose I start at 0 and the constraints are -5 and + 5. Let's say my goal is to reach 2. If I reach -5, then I will bounce back to -4



"Note that for meeting within a range in my special case is a simple modification to my formula." . Could you please write this modification in your answer? Thank you so much



I agree that in the non-integer case, if the step size is integer and the stopping condition is non-integer, then the probability is 0. Now, let's think of the non-integer case where the stopping condition is also non integer (i.e. continuous step size and continuous stopping condition). Can you please mathematically elaborate on this in the answer? thank you so much for all your help

