Does a Normal Distribution have a Stationary Distribution?
In this (great) link here about the Metropolis Hastings algorithm,  https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/11/02/metropolis-hastings/, a proof is shown which states the following: If a Probability Transition Kernel $P(x,y)$ satisfies the Detailed Balanced Condition, then it will have a Stationary Distribution of $\pi(x)$:
Transition Kernel describes the probability of moving from point $x$ to region $A$ :
$$
P^{(n)}(x,A)  = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P^{(n-1)}(x,dy)P(y,A)
$$
$$\pi ^\ast (dy) = \pi(y) dy = \int_R d P(x,dy) \pi(x) dx.$$
$$
\text{Detailed Balance Condition: } \pi(x) \cdot P(x,y) = \pi(y) \cdot P(y,x)
$$
Thus, if the Detailed Balanced Condition is satisfied, we can show the following statement about the existence of the Stationary Distribution:
$$\begin{align*}
& \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P(x,A) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left[ \int_A p(x,y)1(x \in A^c) dy + r(x)1(x \in A) \right] \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left[ \int_A p(x,y)1(x \in A^c) dy \right] \pi(x) dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} r(x)1(x \in A) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left[ \int_A p(x,y)1(x \in A^c) dy \right] \pi(x) dx + \int_A r(x) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_A \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(x,y) \pi(x) dx \right] 1(x \in A^c) dy + \int_A r(x) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \star \int_A \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(y,x) \pi(y) dx \right] 1(x \in A^c) dy + \int_A r(x) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_A (1-r(y)) \pi(y) dy + \int_A r(x) \pi(x) dx \\
&= \int_A \pi(x) dx.
\end{align*}$$
I have a general question about the existence of a Stationary Distribution for a Continuous State Space Stochastic Process (not even related to Metropolis Hastings, but in general).
In this previous question (Can this integral equation be solved?), I showed that a Gaussian Transition Kernel satisfies the Detailed Balanced Condition:
Proof:
consider a Gaussian Transition Kernel that describes the probability of moving from point $x$ to $x'$:
$$T(x, x') \sim N(x, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
The Gaussian Distribution is symmetric, i.e. $f(x) = f(-x)$. This can be shown as follows:
I know that the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean (Proof that the gaussian distribution is "symmetric".), i.e. $f(x) = f(-x)$. This means:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = f(-x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(-x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
I thought of the following way to show this:
If the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean point $\mu$, this means that any two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are equidistant from $\mu$ will have the following properties:
$$x_1 - \mu = \mu - x_2$$
$$\mu = \frac{x_1 +x_2}{2}$$
$$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$$
$$f(\mu + \Delta) = f(\mu - \Delta)$$
Symmetry using this condition implies that:
$$ \exp\left[ - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1 - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_2 - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] $$
Looking at the LHS, we see:
$$ \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1 - \frac{{x_1 + x_2}}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] =  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{2x_1 - (x_1 + x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{x_1 - x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{ 
 {x_1 - x_2)}}   {2\cdot\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$
Now, the same is true for the RHS:
$$ \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_2 - \frac{{x_1 + x_2}}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] =  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{2x_2 - (x_1 + x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{x_1 - x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{ 
 {x_1 - x_2)}}   {2\cdot\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$
Thus, we can see that LHS = RHS and that the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean.
Using the fact that the Gaussian distribution is symmetric, i.e $e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = e^{-\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, we can write:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}$$
Thus, based on the assumption that $\pi(x)$ is Gaussian, we can show that $\pi(x)$ satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition and is a Stationary Distribution:
$$\int T(x, x')\pi(x)dx = \pi(x'), \quad \forall x'$$
Substituting the Gaussian transition kernel $T(x, x')$ and assume $\pi(x)$ is a Gaussian distribution, we get:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}, \quad \forall x'$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}, \quad \forall x'$$
Thus, if I have understood correctly, it would seem to me that the Gaussian Transition Kernel should have a Stationary Distribution (as it satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition).
However, I wrote an R simulation which seems to suggest otherwise:
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

mu <- 0
sigma <- 1

# number of simulations (n) and burn-in observations (m)
n <- 10000
m <- 1000


chain <- numeric(n)
chain[1] <- rnorm(1, mean = mu, sd = sigma)


for (i in 2:n) {
    chain[i] <- rnorm(1, mean = chain[i - 1], sd = sigma)
}


df <- data.frame(Value = chain, Time = 1:n)


cumulative_mean <- numeric(n)
cumulative_variance <- numeric(n)


for (i in 1:n) {
    cumulative_mean[i] <- mean(chain[1:i])
    cumulative_variance[i] <- var(chain[1:i])
}


p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = chain)) +
    geom_line(color = "green") +
    geom_vline(xintercept = m, size = 1, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +  # Pre-burn-in line
    geom_vline(xintercept = n, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +  
    labs(
        title = "X-values of Gaussian Transition Kernel",
        x = "Time",
        y = "X-value"
    ) +
    theme_minimal()

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = cumulative_mean)) +
    geom_line(color = "blue") +
    labs(
        title = "Cumulative Mean Estimation",
        x = "Time",
        y = "Cumulative Mean"
    ) +
    theme_minimal()


p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = cumulative_variance)) +
    geom_line(color = "red") +
    labs(
        title = "Cumulative Variance Estimation",
        x = "Time",
        y = "Cumulative Variance"
    ) +
    theme_minimal()


grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)


It appears that the mean and variance estimates keep increasing with the number of simulations, thus itself showing that the distribution is not "Stationary".
I also tried to do this from first principles:
$$
X_t = 
\begin{cases} 
  N(0, \sigma^2) & \text{if } t = 0 \\
  N(X_{t-1}, \sigma^2) & \text{if } t > 0 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
E[X_t] = E[X_0] + E[X_1] + E[X_2] + ... + E[X_{t-1}]
$$
$$
E[X_t] = N(0, \sigma^2) + N(X_1 - X_0, \sigma^2) + N(X_2 - X_1, \sigma^2) + ... + N(X_{t-1} - X_{t-2}, \sigma^2)
$$
$$
Var[X_t] = Var[X_0] + Var[X_1] + Var[X_2] + ... + Var[X_{t-1}]
$$
$$
Var[X_t] = N(0, \sigma^2) + N(X_1 - X_0, \sigma^2) + N(X_2 - X_1, \sigma^2) + ... + N(X_{t-1} - X_{t-2}, \sigma^2) = n \cdot \sigma^2
$$
Using the properties of the Gaussian Distribution (e.g. affine sums), I think that $X_t$ will also follow a Gaussian Distribution - however, the parameters of this Gaussian Distribution will obviously not be stable and increase with the number of simulations.
My Question: Thus, it seems to me that even though the Gaussian Transition Kernel obeys the Detailed Balanced Condition, for some reason there is still no Stationary Distribution. And to me, this is a contradiction?
Can someone please help me understand this point?
Thanks!

UPDATE: However, now I am not sure if the Gaussian Transition Kernel actually satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition. If in fact the Gaussian Transition Kernel DOES NOT satisfy the Detailed Balance Condition, then it would make sense to believe that the Gaussian Transition Kernel DOES NOT have a Stationary Distribution.
Can it be mathematically proven that the Gaussian Transition Kernel does not satisfy the Detailed Balance Condition?


Why $(x + (-\mu))^2 = (x + \mu)^2$ ?

Moreover, the Detailed Balance Condition must be satisfied for every $x, x'$. What you shown is that $$ \exp\left(-\dfrac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\mu^2}\right)  = \exp\left(-\dfrac{(x' - \mu)^2}{2\mu^2}\right)$$ which is true if and only if $\vert x - \mu \vert = \vert x' - \mu \vert$, so your claim that it satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition doesn't make sense

@stats_noob: It's been too long for me to even attempt to help ( memory is failing more and more ) but here's something that looks pretty useful as far as explaining detailed balance conditions. She writes very clearly. https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~holmescerfon/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture3_2022.pdf

@stats_noob: I know you said that you were looking at it in general but here's one that talks about it in the context of MH. I remember being somewhat enlightened roughly 20 years ago when I read this. http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/Basic/ChibGreenberg1995.pdf

@Thành Nguyễn: thank you for your reply and for pointing out that mistake. I have spent some time and provided a new analysis for showing why the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean point.

@Thành Nguyễn: Is it possible to outright show that the Gaussian Transition Kernel does not satisfy the Detailed Balance Condition?

@ Mark Leeds: Thank you for all these references!

@stats_noob: I'm not sure that you can do what you are trying to do for the normal distribution. I'm ABSOLUTELY not an expert and barely familar but the transition density often requires what is referred to as the infinitesmal generator. Someone way more knowledgeable than me on this can hopefully say more. I don't want to send you on a wild goose chase to nowhere but this person is a masterful writer as far as clarity with probability and stochastic processes.. https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~holmescerfon/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture10_2022.pdf

@ mark leeds: thank you so much for your comments... I am working on this question here ... any ideas? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4903926/when-is-the-hitting-time-of-a-random-walk-infinite thank you so much!
